# I have implemented section index in UITableView, when i tap the section it throws me an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting the array from `JSON`. I have implemented section index in `UITableView` and when I tap the section it throws me an error.

Note: Passing array is from JSON and alphabet array is abcd like that. The error I am getting is `[__NSDictionaryM substringToIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Please help me out. I am retrieving this from contacts and passing those contact in my JSON:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return alphabetsArray.count; 
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 30;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if ([passingArray count] > 0) {

        return [passingArray count];
    }
    else
        return 1;
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return alphabetsArray;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    for (int i = 0; i < [passingArray count]; i++) {

        NSString *letterString = [[passingArray objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:1];
        if ([letterString isEqualToString:title]) {
            [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

- (void)CreateIndexArray {
    NSMutableArray *tempFirstLetterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [passingArray count]; i++) {
        NSString *letterString = [[passingArray objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:1];
        if (![tempFirstLetterArray containsObject:letterString]) {
            [tempFirstLetterArray addObject:letterString];
        }
    }
    passingArray = tempFirstLetterArray;
}
```

Comment: sectionForSectionIndexTitle always return -1?

Comment: I have changed but thats not working

Comment: i have no idea how this works in Json please help me out

Comment: show the output of `passingArray `.

Comment: @arunSwifty you can set an All Exceptions breakpoint. And debug where the error occurred. Some how index is larger than array count. Find out that by debug.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic for `sectionForSectionIndexTitle:` is flawed. That method expects an integer return value - the index to which the tableview should scroll down to.

Also is `passingArray` an array of dictionaries? That is what the error suggests

`[passingArray objectAtIndex:i]` should return a string if you wish to use it with `substringToIndex:`, not a dictionary. If the object is a dictionary, get the correct value from in there using whatever key you have and then run string operations on that value.

Comment: So you want me to convert passing array to string?No passing array is not a dictionary.

Comment: `[__NSDictionaryM substringToIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` - this does mean `substringToIndex:` is being called on a dictionary - that means `passingArray` consists of dictionaries, not strings i.e. `passingArray` is an array of dictionaries